# Grab string between HTML tags

Tags: python, string, text, split

I have a long string of HTML code. I'm looking to grab all text in-between two specific tags which are: `<row>` and `</row>`

for example:

```
str = "<row> hello, this is an example </row> more example text <row> even more </row>
```

desired output:

```
new_list = ['hello, this is an example', 'even more']
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with re to catch the text between row tags:

```
import re


str = "<row> hello, this is an example </row> more example text <row> even more </row>"
test=re.findall('<row>(.*?)</row>',str)
print(test)
```

result:

```
[' hello, this is an example ', ' even more ']
```

Comment: What happens when tags are nested? You famously can’t parse HTML with regex. Please **don’t provide regex answers to complex parsing problems** without at least addressing the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Using an [HTML parser library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import bs4

s = "<row> hello, this is an example </row> more example text <row> even more </row>"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s)
result = [str(x) for x in soup.find_all('row')]
```

Unlike an answer based on pure tokenisation (e.g. via regular expressions), this will continue to work when the HTML tags are nested.